# How do I solve the following multivariable minimization optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_3 + b_4 x _4\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1\\ & \end{array}$$

$$d(1)x(1) +d(2)x(2) + d(3)x(3) + d(4)x(4) \leq Dt$$

$$b(1) >  b(2) > b(3) > b(4) $$

$$d(1) <  d(2) <  d(3) <  d(4) $$

- The four variables $x(1)$ to $x(4)$ represent percentages and must add up to $1$
- Is there a minimum for the objective function such that all the constraints are satisified? How to approach such a problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you correctly formulate the problem? You want to minimize the sum, but you claim that it is equal to $1.$

Comment: As it is stated, if the admissible region, $S$, is non-empty, the minimum is 1 and that value is attained at every point in $S$. Maybe you want to drop the restriction (2)?

Comment: @MohamedR it is good now. Just one thing: it is not clear what is $f(b).$

Comment: I edited a bit. Please edit the rest.

Comment: @user376343 I apologize, I initially called the objective function f(b). I did however edit it out but forgot to edit it out from the question. I did edit it out now. Would you be able to provide any input on how to solve the problem?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for your edits. Would you be able to provide any input on how to solve the problem or if there are any issues with the formulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

$$
\cases{
f(x) = \sum_k b_k x_k^2\\
r_1(x) = \sum_k x_k^2 - 1\\
r_2(x,s) = \sum_k d_k x_k^2-D+s^2
}
$$

we have the lagrangian

$$
L(x,\lambda,\mu,s) = f(x)+\lambda r_1(x)+\mu r_2(x,s)
$$

here $s$ is a slack variable to transform the inequality into an equivalent equation.

The **stationary points** are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \cases{ 
b_j x_j+\lambda x_j + \mu d_j x_j = 0,\ \ j=1,\cdots,4\\
\sum_k x_k^2 - 1=0\\
\sum_k d_k x_k^2-D+s^2=0\\
\mu s = 0
}
$$

giving

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
f & x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 & x_4^2 & \lambda &\mu & s^2 & \text{condition}\\
 b_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -b_1 & 0 & D-d_1 & D\ge d_1\\
 b_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -b_2 & 0 & D-d_2 & D\ge d_2\\
 b_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -b_3 & 0 & D-d_3 & D \ge d_3\\
 b_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -b_4 & 0 & D-d_4 & D\ge d_4\\
 \frac{b_2 \left(d_1-D\right)}{d_1-d_2}+\frac{b_1 \left(d_2-D\right)}{d_2-d_1} & \frac{d_2-D}{d_2-d_1} &
   \frac{d_1-D}{d_1-d_2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{b_1 d_2-b_2 d_1}{d_1-d_2} & \frac{b_2-b_1}{d_1-d_2} & 0 & d_1\le D\le d_2\\
 \frac{b_3 \left(d_1-D\right)}{d_1-d_3}+\frac{b_1 \left(d_3-D\right)}{d_3-d_1} & \frac{d_3-D}{d_3-d_1} & 0 &
   \frac{d_1-D}{d_1-d_3} & 0 & \frac{b_1 d_3-b_3 d_1}{d_1-d_3} & \frac{b_3-b_1}{d_1-d_3} & 0 & d_1\le D\le d_3\\
 \frac{b_3 \left(d_2-D\right)}{d_2-d_3}+\frac{b_2 \left(d_3-D\right)}{d_3-d_2} & 0 & \frac{d_3-D}{d_3-d_2} &
   \frac{d_2-D}{d_2-d_3} & 0 & \frac{b_2 d_3-b_3 d_2}{d_2-d_3} & \frac{b_3-b_2}{d_2-d_3} & 0 & d_2\le D\le d_3\\
 \frac{b_4 \left(d_1-D\right)}{d_1-d_4}+\frac{b_1 \left(d_4-D\right)}{d_4-d_1} & \frac{d_4-D}{d_4-d_1} & 0 & 0 &
   \frac{d_1-D}{d_1-d_4} & \frac{b_1 d_4-b_4 d_1}{d_1-d_4} & \frac{b_4-b_1}{d_1-d_4} & 0 & d_1\le D \le d_4\\
 \frac{b_4 \left(d_2-D\right)}{d_2-d_4}+\frac{b_2 \left(d_4-D\right)}{d_4-d_2} & 0 & \frac{d_4-D}{d_4-d_2} & 0 &
   \frac{d_2-D}{d_2-d_4} & \frac{b_2 d_4-b_4 d_2}{d_2-d_4} & \frac{b_4-b_2}{d_2-d_4} & 0 & d_2\le D \le d_4\\
 \frac{b_4 \left(d_3-D\right)}{d_3-d_4}+\frac{b_3 \left(d_4-D\right)}{d_4-d_3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{d_4-D}{d_4-d_3} &
   \frac{d_3-D}{d_3-d_4} & \frac{b_3 d_4-b_4 d_3}{d_3-d_4} & \frac{b_4-b_3}{d_3-d_4} & 0 &d_3\le D \le d_4\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

We used $x_k^2$ to assure the positiveness. When $s=0$ indicates that $r_2(x,s)$ is actuating. The table of results should be interpreted according to the given condition at the last column.

Attached a python script to check the found stationary points. Note that the python solver only catches one solution. Changing the values for `D0` we can observe the diverse solutions.

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

b1 = 9
b2 = 8
b3 = 7
b4 = 6
d1 = 2
d2 = 4
d3 = 6 
d4 = 8
D0 = 5
res = \
[[b1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -b1, 0, D0 - d1], 
 [b2, 0, 1, 0, 0, -b2, 0, D0 - d2], 
 [b3, 0, 0, 1, 0, -b3, 0, D0 - d3], 
 [b4, 0, 0, 0, 1, -b4, 0, D0 - d4], 
 [(b2*(-D0 + d1))/(d1 - d2) + (b1*(-D0 + d2))/(-d1 + d2), (-D0 + d2)/(-d1 + d2), (-D0 + d1)/(d1 - d2), 0, 0, (-b2*d1 + b1*d2)/(d1 - d2), (-b1 + b2)/(d1 - d2), 0], 
 [(b3*(-D0 + d1))/(d1 - d3) + (b1*(-D0 + d3))/(-d1 + d3), (-D0 + d3)/(-d1 + d3), 0, (-D0 + d1)/(d1 - d3), 0, (-b3*d1 + b1*d3)/(d1 - d3), (-b1 + b3)/(d1 - d3), 0], 
 [(b3*(-D0 + d2))/(d2 - d3) + (b2*(-D0 + d3))/(-d2 + d3), 0, (-D0 + d3)/(-d2 + d3), (-D0 + d2)/(d2 - d3), 0, (-b3*d2 + b2*d3)/(d2 - d3), (-b2 + b3)/(d2 - d3), 0], 
 [(b4*(-D0 + d1))/(d1 - d4) + (b1*(-D0 + d4))/(-d1 + d4), (-D0 + d4)/(-d1 + d4), 0, 0, (-D0 + d1)/(d1 - d4), (-b4*d1 + b1*d4)/(d1 - d4), (-b1 + b4)/(d1 - d4), 0], 
 [(b4*(-D0 + d2))/(d2 - d4) + (b2*(-D0 + d4))/(-d2 + d4), 0, (-D0 + d4)/(-d2 + d4), 0, (-D0 + d2)/(d2 - d4), (-b4*d2 + b2*d4)/(d2 - d4), (-b2 + b4)/(d2 - d4), 0], 
 [(b4*(-D0 + d3))/(d3 - d4) + (b3*(-D0 + d4))/(-d3 + d4), 0, 0, (-D0 + d4)/(-d3 + d4), (-D0 + d3)/(d3 - d4), (-b4*d3 + b3*d4)/(d3 - d4), (-b3 + b4)/(d3 - d4), 0]
]

print("------stationary points------")

for i in range(10):
    resi = res[i]
    OK = True
    for j in range(5):
        if resi[j] < 0:
            OK = False
    if resi[7] < 0:
        OK = False
    if OK: 
        print(resi[0],[resi[1],resi[2],resi[3],resi[4]])
    
print(30*'-')
print("------------result------------")
obj      = [b1, b2, b3, b4]
lhs_eq   = [[1, 1, 1, 1]]
rhs_eq   = [1]
lhs_ineq = [[d1, d2, d3, d4]]
rhs_ineq = [D0]
bnd      = [(0,float("inf")),(0,float("inf")),(0,float("inf")),(0,float("inf"))]
opt      = linprog(c=obj, A_ub=lhs_ineq, b_ub=rhs_ineq, A_eq=lhs_eq, b_eq=rhs_eq, bounds=bnd, method="revised simplex")
print(opt.fun, opt.x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do have two questions however. 1) If the value of $D$ is larger than $d_4$, and the value of $s$ is zero, what would be the value of function? 2) Is there any condition where all of the $x$ variables have non-zero values and all of the constraints are satisfied?

Comment: I will include ASAP a python script using a solver and showing as the stationary points are obeyed.

Comment: Included the python script.